# Blending a transparent image shows a white factor

Tags: opengl-es

Why does the image shows white , when its alpha factor has been made zero. It should be completely Transparent. I am using the Blending Function as glBlend(GL_ONE,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA).

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense, for details read the [official documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml) really carefully.

But for a simple explanation let me give you a simple example. So imagine your source is `(255,0,0,0)` (using an (R,G,B,A) notation) and you destination is `(0,255,0,0)`. The source value is weighted with `GL_ONE` which translates to `(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)` and the source with `(1-0.0f,1-0.0f,1-0.0f,1-0.0f)` because your `SRC_ALPHA` is `0`. So the simplified calculation for the color would be:

```
R = 255 * 1.0f + 0   * 1.0f = 255
G = 0   * 1.0f + 255 * 1.0f = 255
B = 0   * 1.0f + 0   * 1.0f = 0
A = 0   * 1.0f + 0   * 1.0f = 0
    |      |      |     |
    |      |      |   destination weight
    |      |      |
    |      |    destination color
    |      |
    |     source weight
    |
  source color
```

So your final color would be `(255,255,0,0)`. You may be confused by the fact that the source after being weighted with `GL_ONE` has an alpha of `0` but that doesn't mean anything because you didn't tell OpenGL to use that alpha value for anything.

Also, remember that this is simplified and if you provided a vertex color there may also be some interaction with `glTexEnv` and its `GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE` setting.